# "Зачесал на бок" в предложении

Tags: недопустимая-метка

"Зачесал волосы на бок" раздельно ведь?

Comment: Интересно, на каком боку у кого растут волосы, вообще-то они на голове.

Answer (score 1):

Слитно. Это наречие - признак, дающий дополнительное определение глаголу или прилагательному. "Зачесал волосы набок", "шляпа съехала набок", ведь здесь имеется в виду не какой-то конкретный "бок", а наклон чего-либо в сторону.

Answer (score 1):

**Зачесал волосы набок.** В данном случае правильным будет слитное написание   – **набок.**

*На бок.*

Написание бывает раздельным, если в предложении находится выраженное имя существительное с предлогом. В этом случае вопросы «на что?» или «куда?» становятся намного более предпочтительными, чем «как?». А ударение, как правило, ставится не на предлог, а на само существительное. Например: «На бок коровы села бабочка», «Я смотрел на бок лодки и удивлялся его гладкости», «Он повернулся на спину, а потом на бок».

*Набок.*

**А если в предложении уместен вопрос «как?», то это наречие, которое пишется слитно.** Например: «Наклонённый набок гвоздь торчал из стены». У гвоздя вообще-то нет боков. И определение «набок» будет не буквальным. Не бока имеются в виду, а отклонение от симметрии.

Comment: А может человек упасть "набок"? Или только "на бок"?